# Spring Security intercept does not work

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting started with spring security via java configurations, but when i go to http://localhost:8080/myapp , i am not redirected to the login form, as we expected.

I have the basic configurations, i have been following [this guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration).

I am using Spring Security 3.2.5.RELEASE and Spring Version 4.1.2.RELEASE.

This is my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
}
```

and my security initializer:

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {



}
```

My Spring Servlet Dispatcher:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What is the web server you are using? and are you using Spring Web MVC as well?

Comment: I am using jetty via gradle, and yes, i am using Spring Web MVC too.

Comment: Please show the code for your Spring Web MVC DispatcherServlet registering

Comment: What is the no in your web.xml web-app version. It must be 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem in your case is that `springSecurityFilterChain` is not being created because your `SecurityConfig` is not being scanned.

Many things can be reason for this;

1. Your web container doesn't support Web Application 3.0 (Only Jetty 8.x supported)
2. You have no `@ComponentScan` to cover `SecurityConfig` so that it can register filter bean `springSecurityFilterChain`

You must either Register the `SecurityConfig` class explicitly in your `SecurityInitializer` and make sure the SecurityInitializer is being called.

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried both solutions and none of them worked.
Why if i am using spring should i have to put that constructor (`SecurityInitializer`)?

Comment: Please see the comment. For the AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer to work you need to have Web.xml version 3.0, make sure you have that.

Comment: And i have it: `<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
`

Comment: Ok do you get a 404 /login Not Found? or any other error?

Comment: I have a customized login page on `/login`, i can get that page normally.